# Bootstrap use the space of another column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

I have a react project going at the moment and one of the pages has a sidebar on the left occupying 3 column spaces of the container.

I have the remaining width of the page using 8 more columns for the main content.

The sidebar only has 7-8 links in it. The main content of the page only occupies 8 columns in height. What I need is when the main contents height drops under the sidebar, the content will fill up the remaining whitespace under the sidebar rather than continuing straight down with whitespace left under the sidebar.

I made a dummy html code in [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/secretdose/qs2z0cp6/6/). What I need is the main content to take up the remaining container space including under the sidebar like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx24B.png).( image edited using photoshop, sorry for bad layout)

I searched roughly for 2 hours and couldn't find an answer, or maybe I don't know how to phrase what I'm looking for.

Code: `

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">



    <style>
        .container {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        li {
            margin: 30px;
        }
        .main-text {
            border: 3px dashed red;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .overflow-text {
            border: 3px solid blue;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 ">
                <ul style="border: 2px solid black">
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                    <li>List item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="main-text">
                    <h3>Main Content</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In tempora libero
                        placeat culpa nostrum dignissimos deserunt nisi dolorum dolore repudiandae necessitatibus
                        numquam architecto laudantium, asperiores, tenetur exercitationem molestias quo explicabo
                        officia sequi ad. Qui fugiat praesentium reiciendis nulla officia, debitis eveniet,
                        reprehenderit id nisi assumenda, nemo perferendis corporis magnam! Voluptatem nam sapiente,
                        tempore molestiae aspernatur voluptatibus impedit! Omnis facilis ut, vel rerum doloremque,
                        sunt
                        consequatur quaerat eligendi soluta, ratione accusantium hic saepe officia maiores enim
                        voluptate id? Neque, enim ipsam rerum, praesentium, autem eaque similique voluptas ratione
                        culpa
                        impedit harum dolor consequatur voluptatem eveniet nesciunt itaque doloremque aperiam
                        repellat
                        facilis incidunt atque animi voluptatum ex! Adipisci vitae autem deserunt vero porro amet
                        modi
                        omnis quidem aliquam tempore sit cupiditate eos obcaecati nostrum reprehenderit, harum
                        fugiat!
                        Est fugit expedita exercitationem mollitia nulla nemo iure esse deserunt! Nostrum laboriosam
                        doloribus molestiae qui aut excepturi, impedit nulla quam sint quisquam veritatis id
                        expedita,
                        velit dolores voluptates quos ipsam tempore nihil consectetur repudiandae. Cum recusandae
                        laboriosam facere numquam laudantium! Unde deleniti delectus facilis, quaerat dolorem quas
                        pariatur repellat. Unde voluptatibus atque aliquid amet, eaque hic dicta facere vitae eius?
                        Tempora hic pariatur vel reiciendis vitae, rerum necessitatibus repellendus, culpa
                        perspiciatis
                        maxime voluptatibus. In error reiciendis, aliquid illo aperiam, magnam optio ipsam, ratione
                        quam
                        perspiciatis dolorum minima repellat possimus quod dolore ea? Ea inventore perspiciatis esse
                        est
                        cum fuga praesentium sed, eum totam dolor quas accusamus iusto aperiam veritatis id, culpa
                        neque
                        omnis mollitia nostrum repudiandae, optio sit explicabo accusantium illo. Suscipit libero
                        distinctio rem quas non eveniet recusandae! Ipsum tempora cumque deserunt, perferendis
                        eligendi
                        nisi accusantium fugiat exercitationem rem qui expedita labore quam ea quasi voluptatum et
                        eos
                        alias atque, consequuntur repellat vero! Incidunt, reprehenderit cupiditate at, deserunt
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis fugiat omnis sequi
                        pariatur. Accusantium odit aut error. Iusto quos modi temporibus, libero minus, laboriosam
                        veritatis dignissimos laborum ullam ea pariatur nihil blanditiis nobis sapiente doloremque
                        illo explicabo! Sapiente quaerat iure dignissimos, deserunt illum delectus aperiam accusamus
                        accusantium adipisci libero eveniet.

                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure you can do what you want by putting your links in one column and the text in another, but you could put them into separate divisions and then float the link div for larger displays.

```css
.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

li {
    margin: 30px;
}

.main-text {
    border: 3px dashed red;
    padding: 20px;
}

.overflow-text {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="float-md-start me-md-3">
                    <ul class="mb-1" style="border: 2px solid black">
                        <li><a href="https://google.com">List item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://google.com">List item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://google.com">List item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://google.com">List item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://google.com">List item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://google.com">List item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://google.com">List item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="main-text">
                    <h3>Main Content</h3>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In tempora libero placeat culpa nostrum dignissimos deserunt nisi dolorum dolore repudiandae necessitatibus numquam architecto laudantium, asperiores, tenetur exercitationem molestias quo explicabo officia sequi ad. Qui fugiat praesentium reiciendis nulla officia, debitis eveniet, reprehenderit id nisi assumenda, nemo perferendis corporis magnam! Voluptatem nam sapiente, tempore molestiae aspernatur voluptatibus impedit! Omnis facilis ut, vel rerum doloremque, sunt consequatur quaerat eligendi soluta, ratione accusantium hic saepe officia maiores enim voluptate id? Neque, enim ipsam rerum, praesentium, autem eaque similique voluptas ratione culpa impedit harum dolor consequatur voluptatem eveniet nesciunt itaque doloremque aperiam repellat facilis incidunt atque animi voluptatum ex! Adipisci vitae autem deserunt vero porro amet modi omnis quidem aliquam tempore sit cupiditate eos obcaecati nostrum reprehenderit, harum fugiat! Est fugit expedita exercitationem mollitia nulla nemo iure esse deserunt! Nostrum laboriosam doloribus molestiae qui aut excepturi, impedit nulla quam sint quisquam veritatis id expedita, velit dolores voluptates quos ipsam tempore nihil consectetur repudiandae. Cum recusandae laboriosam facere numquam laudantium! Unde deleniti delectus facilis, quaerat dolorem quas pariatur repellat. Unde voluptatibus atque aliquid amet, eaque hic dicta facere vitae eius? Tempora hic pariatur vel reiciendis vitae, rerum necessitatibus repellendus, culpa perspiciatis maxime voluptatibus. In error reiciendis, aliquid illo aperiam, magnam optio ipsam, ratione quam perspiciatis dolorum minima repellat possimus quod dolore ea? Ea inventore perspiciatis esse est cum fuga praesentium sed, eum totam dolor quas accusamus iusto aperiam veritatis id, culpa neque omnis mollitia nostrum repudiandae, optio sit explicabo accusantium illo. Suscipit libero distinctio rem quas non eveniet recusandae! Ipsum tempora cumque deserunt, perferendis eligendi nisi accusantium fugiat exercitationem rem qui expedita labore quam ea quasi voluptatum et eos alias atque, consequuntur repellat vero! Incidunt, reprehenderit cupiditate at, deserunt Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis fugiat omnis sequi pariatur. Accusantium odit aut error. Iusto quos modi temporibus, libero minus, laboriosam veritatis dignissimos laborum ullam ea pariatur nihil blanditiis nobis sapiente doloremque illo explicabo! Sapiente quaerat iure dignissimos, deserunt illum delectus aperiam accusamus accusantium adipisci libero eveniet.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but all of my links become unclickable. I still couldn't find a solution to this, I am not sure what I will do.